# Deserializing Json Response to a Dictionary<string, object> throws error : unexpected end when deserializing object

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

Hi i am trying to deserialize a json response like below

```
{     
    [ 
        { 
            "WebCash" : { 
                "Id" : 1021,
                "RedemptionCode" : "sdfkjk",
                "PlayerCardId" : "3802",
                "Amount" : 8000,
                "Status" : 1,
                "PurchaseTimeStamp" : 1445020270,
                "RedeemTimeStamp" : 1445021971,
                "RetailerId" : "1781",
                "TerminalId" : "9",
            }, { 
                "Id" : 1160,
                "RedemptionCode" : "9123LKBJFDAXEK8194",
                "PlayerCardId" : "3802",
                "Amount" : 10000,
                "Status" : 3,
                "PurchaseTimeStamp" : 1445020270,
                "RetailerId" : "1781",
                "TerminalId" : "9",
            }
       } 
    ]
}
```

It works fine when we don't have different blocks but throws error when we have the response type as { [ {, ,}, {, ,} ] }

I am using the following code

```
String Expected_Response = Response;
Dictionary<String, Object> ActualResponse_Dic = null; 
ActualResponse_Dic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<String, Object>>(ResponseValue);  //ResponseValue holds the entire Json response string
```

It throws error at the last line
unexpected end when deserializing object Path....

Comment: Where is the second key in your json string?

Comment: It's failing because that isn't valid JSON.  Run it through a validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comment provided by Amy.  Try the following:

- Remove the outermost braces {}
- Remove the commas after "TerminalId": "9"
- Place brackets [] around the "WebCash" objects:

Perhaps like the below:

```
[{
"WebCash": [{
    "Id": 1021,
    "RedemptionCode": "sdfkjk",
    "PlayerCardId": "3802",
    "Amount": 8000,
    "Status": 1,
    "PurchaseTimeStamp": 1445020270,
    "RedeemTimeStamp": 1445021971,
    "RetailerId": "1781",
    "TerminalId": "9"
}, {
    "Id": 1160,
    "RedemptionCode": "9123LKBJFDAXEK8194",
    "PlayerCardId": "3802",
    "Amount": 10000,
    "Status": 3,
    "PurchaseTimeStamp": 1445020270,
    "RetailerId": "1781",
    "TerminalId": "9"
}]
}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..i am little knew to JSON structure. This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid. Additionally, **Dictionary < String, Object >** would probably be serialized to something like this:

```
    { 
        "WebCash" : { 
            "Id" : 1021,
            "RedemptionCode" : "sdfkjk",
            "PlayerCardId" : "3802",
            "Amount" : 8000,
            "Status" : 1,
            "PurchaseTimeStamp" : 1445020270,
            "RedeemTimeStamp" : 1445021971,
            "RetailerId" : "1781",
            "TerminalId" : "9"
        }, 
        "WebCash2" : { 
            "Id" : 1160,
            "RedemptionCode" : "9123LKBJFDAXEK8194",
            "PlayerCardId" : "3802",
            "Amount" : 10000,
            "Status" : 3,
            "PurchaseTimeStamp" : 1445020270,
            "RetailerId" : "1781",
            "TerminalId" : "9"
        }
   }
```